# React Rendering Text in a Mapped Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm currently trying to render a list of podcasts from the iTunes API in a list and display all of them on my page.

Here's my code: https://gist.github.com/JelaniThompson/bd5d9127b80641b4483b9273f97df289

On line 24, I define my display variable and then render it in the return statement but it isn't appearing. However, when I log the same value to the console all of the show names are appearing.

What would be the correct way to display my array values on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it will not!
and that's because first names is an empty array!

Solution:

1- add this to the class and remove names, images, and summaries from the top of the file:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)  
  this.state = {
    names : [],
    images : [],
    summaries : []
  } 
}
```

2- call fetch data in the constructor and remove it from the render method (You shouldn't do any thing that calls render inside render, you will end up having an infinite loop!):

```
 constructor(props){
          super(props)  
          this.state = {
            names : [],
            images : [],
            summaries : []
          } 

          let that = this
          fetch(topFifty).then(function(response) {
                    return response.json().then(function(json) {
                        let names = [], images = [], summaries = []
                        json.feed.entry.forEach(function(datum) {
                            names.push(datum["im:name"].label)
                            images.push(datum["im:image"][0].label)
                            summaries.push(datum.summary.label)
                        })
                        that.setState({names:names,
                                      images: images,
                                      summaries: summaries})
                    })
           })
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, that returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined` Is there a better way I could manage the state?

Comment: ok fixed, notice replacing this.setState by that.setState, and adding  let that = this ....